# NodeJS - Removing a particular item from an Array

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm getting list of all collections from mongodb, in form of an array

```
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
   console.log(names);
```

output:

```
[ { name: 'system.indexes' },
  { name: 'books' },
  ...
```

I want to remove that `system.indexes` from the array.  I tried playing around with some functions like:

- Splice
- Pop, Shift
- Underscore's `without`function

Well, Honestly I don't even know if they were intended for this.

Comment: do you want to remove the entire object { name: 'system.indexes' } or just the property of name?

Comment: @Bernhard the entire object. so the output result would be `[ { name: 'books' }, ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the objects where name is equal to `system.indexes` do it as follow:

```
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
   if (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }else{
     var i;

     for(i=names.length - 1; i >= 0; i-=1){
        if(names[i].name !== 'system.indexes'){
            names.splice(i,1);
        }
     }

     // names now contain all items without the system.indexes
   }
```

Comment: Well, thx it does work. But I'm confused. Do we really have to do it this way? I mean using a loop and recreating the array is kinda..old fashioned.

Comment: @xperator You're right in plain javascript it's better to iterate backwards. Updated my answer